# unliking gives me facebook error via graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using graph api.

Two facebook accounts who are friends. 
First guy posts( id of post be : **postid1**) and is visible to second guy. Secondy guy likes(suceeds). 
Now when second guy tries to unlike what he liked before facebook throws me the below error.

```
{
   "error":{
      "message":"(#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application",
      "type":"OAuthException",
      "code":200
   }
}
```

I am making the below http request for unlike
Delete https://graph.facebook.com:443/**postid1**/likes?access_token=abc

Can some one point me what's the mistake I am doing.